# How to understand [this code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/416s737WK) in the right way?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

How to understand [this code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/416s737WK) in the right way?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
 
#ifdef MORE_QUESTION
void f(std::initializer_list<int> const &items){};
void g(std::vector<int> const &items){};
#endif

struct foo {
    template<typename T>  
    foo(std::initializer_list<T>) {std::cout << "here" << std::endl;} 
};

int main()
{
    foo x{1,2,3}; // What's this?

#ifdef MORE_QUESTION
    f({1,2,3,4}); 
    g({1,2,3,4}); 
#endif
}
```

Questions about the said code snippet:

What's `foo x{1,2,3};`?

Comment: please one question per question. And for non working code you should include the compiler error message in the quesiton

Comment: `foo x{1,2,3};` is a form of _direct-list-initialization_. For more details see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization. Note that there are special rules related to `std::initializer_list` and there are no such rules for `std::vector`.

Comment: `foo x{1,2,3};` defines a variable named `x` of type `foo`, and initializes it by invoking `foo` constructor that takes `std::initializer_list` as a parameter. Similarly, `f({1,2,3,4});` calls a function `f` passing an initializer list as a parameter. `g({1,2,3,4});` constructs a temporary `std::vector<int>` from the initializer list, and then passes that temporary to function `g`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I can understand `foo x({1,2,3});`. I have difficulty in understanding `foo x{1,2,3};` .Could you please explain that in more detail for me?

Comment: The search term for further research is "uniform initialization". E.g. `int x(42);`, `int x=42;` and `int x{42};` are all equivalent, three different ways to say the same thing, namely "define a variable named `x` of type `int` and initialize it to the value 42".

Comment: @ Igor Tandetnik For `foo x({1,2,3,4});`, the outer `()` means to call the constructor function and    the inner `{}` means a object of `std::initializer_list`. For `foo x{1,2,3};`, I am totally confused.

Answer (score 0):

> foo x({1,2,3,4});, the outer () means to call the constructor function and the inner {} means a object of std::initializer_list. For foo x{1,2,3};, I am totally confused. –

No, the meaning of "outer ()" and of "the inner{}" isn't quite what you describe. The examples are two (of many) kinds of variable initialization in C++. The outer {} and the outer () only tell you which initialization is to be used, nothing else:

```
T var( stuff ); // direct-initialization

T var{ stuff }; // direct-list-initialization
```

Each can initialize a great many Ts in many different ways from many different kinds of `stuff`. For the long read, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Among the many things `stuff` can be, it can be a comma-separated list of expressions (as in `1,2,3` case) and it can be a brace-enclosed comma-separated list of expressions (as in `{1,2,3}` case).

```
T var(  1,2,3  ); // works for some T
T var( {1,2,3} ); // works for some T
T var{  1,2,3  }; // works for some T
T var{ {1,2,3} }; // works for some T
```

Your type `foo` happens to support 3 of those 4 types of initialization because in this case they all call the same `initializer_list` constructor you provided. For another T, none of them would deal with any `initializer_list`.